# How to save massive data on dynamodb?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs

I'm trying to save massive phone registers to a dynamodb working on docker (local), but everytime that i'm trying to save i get an error

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)`

Here is my code that im trying to call every record that i need to save, working on nest

```
async saveData(saveItem: listUser) {
        const tableName: string = this.userTableName;
        const input = <BatchWriteCommandInput>{};
        input.RequestItems = {};
        input.RequestItems[tableName] = [
            { PutRequest: { Item: saveItem } },
        ];

        const output = await this.dynamoClient.getDocumentClient().send(new BatchWriteCommand(input));

        return output.$metadata.httpStatusCode;
    }
```

**EDIT**

It appears executing the save funtion mutiple times, it works with the first 40 or 50 entries and then shows up this error.

It's the conection error shows up when tryin to save mutiple times

Comment: are you using dynaomdb local? if nothow are you configuring your dynamodb connection?

Comment: Why are you doing a BatchWrite for a single item Put? What causes the issue to arise? Does it happen for every execution of the save function?

Comment: It appears executing the save funtion mutiple times, it works with the first 40 or 50 entries and then shows up this error

Answer (score 0):

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)` states you are trying to connect to localhost on port 8000. If you are using DynamoDB local, ensure the service is running on port 8000 locally.